# Is there a game theory solution for this scenario?

Tags: game-theory

Consider a finite bunch of **publishers** each of whom has put some secret amount of money in a pot to acquire a piece of info. The person who submits the

1. **complete** info to the pot
2. **first**

wins all the money in the pot

3. if there is at least 1 runner up.

The aim of the game is to incentivize complete publication as fast as possible. Is there a game theoretic approach already available that models this scenario?

**Terminology**

By **submission** we mean that the person sends the complete info to the pot. Submissions are private.

By **publication** we mean that a publisher makes its piece of info public to all others.

**End point**: The pot waits for at least 2 submissions and makes the info public.

A **runner up** is the second publisher who submitted the complete info.

e.g. If there were only two people and 3 wasn't applicable, no one would ever publish their piece of info as the non publisher wins. (In fact the last person not publishing would always win). With 3., the last publisher publishes post submission.

Is there a way to ensure everybody does publish?

Feel free to extend the problem.

Comment: This is not clear to me. Doesn't your argument for two people extend to any number of people? How could anyone ever benefit from publish their information before the others?

Comment: You are right the last person always wins by not publishing. Thats actually what I was trying to solve thus the second part...I'll modify the question

Comment: I don't understand the edit. What is a "runner up" in this context? and what does "the last publisher publishes post submission" mean?

Comment: "runner up": at least one other publisher has provided the complete answer-remember that publishers can win by being first and aren't aware of other submissions to pot. So a runner up is a publisher who submitted second. Condition 3 forces the first publisher to actually post its piece of info else it won't win. On the other hand it will do so after providing its own answer to the pot first aka "publish post submission".

Comment: @joriki thnx for taking an interest btw

Comment: I couldn't "remember" that publishers aren't aware of other submissions to the pot because the question currently doesn't say so. This is a crucial part of the setup that should be added to the question. (Not everyone reads the comments.) The question currently only says that the amount of money is secret, not the information. To the contrary, the term "publish" seems to indicate that the information becomes public when submitted. If the information is submitted secretly, you should describe exactly how this process works, how and when the players become aware that the game is over, etc.

Comment: I find this very confusing. The publishers submit money to *aquire* info, but then submit that info? What does "complete info" mean? How does one determine if one has "complete info"? If the first to publish complete info wins, in what way does delaying until a second publisher submits complete info to declare that win incentivize anyone to submit faster?

Comment: "piece of info” complete info is all pieces combined